# Azure storage emulator won't initialize

Tags: visual-studio, azure

On running a project for the first time on Visual Studio 2017, I am getting the following error in the output window.

Microsoft Azure Tools: Failed to initialize Microsoft Azure storage emulator. The storage emulator needs to be initialized. Please run the 'init' command. No available SQL Instance was found.

I do have a local SQL instance on the machine.
I have tried to initialize it from a command prompt running as administrator but get the message telling me I can't run that program on my machine.

Can anyone tell me where I should start looking, as I'm not to sure where to start.

More details:
When starting from the command prompt using -inprocess I get:

Cannot open database "AzureStorageEmulatorDb51" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user xxxxx

thanks